# Select values not included in table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design, relational-database

A friend of mine is making a database on MS Access, and he encountered the following problem.

On his database, he has a table called "bookings". This table keeps track of who has booked each sport hall and when. 
There is a field called "member" that takes values from a "members" table.
There is a field called "hall" that takes values from a "halls" table.
There is a "date" field.
And there is a "time" field which takes values from a "slots" table. This is to obtain a drop down menu with all the possible time slots (09:00, 10:00, etc.. until 22:00).

```
Member  |  hall  |  date  |  time   
--------+--------+--------+--------
Text    |  text  |  date  |  text
Dropdown|dropdown| typed  |dropdown
```

Now, he wants the drop down menu that shows all the times, to show only the times that are not already booked for the selected hall and date.

In order to do this, I believe I need to make a query which will do the following when I input the selected date and sport hall:

SELECT all the time slots WHERE the slot is not already booked in a previous record of the booking tables.

Then I'd need to figure out how to input the inputted values into the query and obtain the results, and then put the results into the options of the drop down menu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First, I assume that 'all halls have all time slots available'? Or can some halls have say noon to 5 instead of 9:00 - 22:00? Then not to make this more difficult, but I assume you allow someone to say 'I need this date, don't care which hall', or 'I need this hall, don't care about date or time'? Your initial dropdown queries can be determined by what is NOT available. Take a look at: https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=240698   or  https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=169635

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn All halls do have all time slots available. And no we don't allow someone to say I need this date, I don't care which hall. But on input, I am trying to get the system to show which times are available once the hall and date are specified

Comment: Here is a really great example of how to do this. I just tried it and it works fine: http://www.datawright.com.au/access_resources/bookings_without_clashes.htm   You need to create the three queries as shown, then once you add the filters, it will show only the times that are available. If you still have questions, let me know and I can post the SQL I created (using MY OWN names!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a separate query to generate a unique number for all the possible dates times and halls, and an identical query to generate the numbers for all booked slots. Then when the date and hall are input, you can generate a unique number for each possible time for that date and hall, after which you can check if that unique number is in the query of booked unique numbers.